# Why is Libre Office Draw and Math still on my main menu

Tags: desktop

So this morning I downloaded the  LibreOffice suite. I just now realized that I am only going to use LibreOffice Writer, and so I deleted the other programs. but, after I updated, upgraded, and rebooted, LibreOffice Draw and Math is still under office in my main menu. I also pasted file, location file, and the target file into Add/Remove software, and it didn't find anything. I tried removing it using Main Menu Editor, and i think i had deleted it. but, when i rebooted and went back into office in my main menu, LibreOffice Draw and Math were still there. finally, i removed the whole LibreOffice suite, and reinstalled it. then i rebooted it, but instead of the normal 7, i only saw three. went into Main Menu Editor, and it says that i don't have LibreOffice Draw or LibreOffice Math. then, i ran sudo apt autoremove, and tried to open Libre office Draw and LibreOffice Math. LibreOffice Math doesn't open, and Libre Office Draw gives me the following error on startup:

Component cannot be loaded, possibly broken or incomplete installation.
Full error message:

loading component library file:///usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libsdlo.so failed ./cppuhelper/source/shlib.cxx:298.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,
SmallComputer12

Comment: @ jsotola. But do you have any ideas that could fix this?

Comment: edit the main menu ... which desktop manager are you using? ... there should be documentation available for doing that

Comment: @ jsotola i believe i use Raspberry Pi OS 11 or 12, and i have a Raspberry PI 4 B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I had to install the whole libreoffice suite, then I had to run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove —-purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
reboot
```